# TypeError: 'click' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLElement

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have some javascript that sends data to a function that calls a php page, however I get an error that I can't find any information on. The postData() call is in the middle of another plain javascript function. But I can't get it to submit the data to the php page.

```
function postData() {
var postdataURL = "path/to/php/page.php";
    $.post (
        postdataURL, {
        "formid":5,
        "clientid":1,
        "userid":1,
        "level":mycat,
        "extra":mytimer,
        "pid":pid
        },
        function () {});
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `postData`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove the " from the name of the properties

```
$.post (
    postdataURL, {
    formid:5,
    clientid:1,
    userid:1,
    level:mycat,
    extra:mytimer,
    pid:pid
    },
    function () {});
```

And add a

```
alert("Got called");
```

after

```
function postData() {
```

to be sure the function is being called

Comment: Why remove the quotes? The two are equivalent, and the quoted version is safer in that you can use names that would otherwise be illegal as identifiers.

Comment: I try to use everything alike the jquery documentation. They never use quotes. Plus I have had some trouble with the quotes before so maybe that helps..

Comment: Thank you for the info that both are equivalent though :)

Comment: It turned out to be one of the values I was passing in the $.post fucnction. Seems some extra value names were configured on our server to be excluded and part of the excluded names list. Thanks for all the suggestions. Chalk one up for another reason for good documentation

Answer (score 9):

Review your variable mycat, mytimer, pid is may be a jQuery Object. 
That mean you had asigned

```
mycat = $('#cate')
```

If that true, you just fix that

```
mycat = $('#cate').val()
```

Or some code get real value.

Answer (score 2):

I ran in to this when doing a jQuery $.ajax() call like you did.  Apparently (in my case) it was caused by referencing a variable that wasn't in scope and was undefined.  For example, in your code:

```
    "level":mycat,
    "extra":mytimer,
    "pid":pid
```

If mycat, mytimer, or pid were null, and you're having the same problem, that would do it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case was the same problem like [@user3740976](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3740976/user3740976). I put in url an undefined parameter.

```
$.ajax({
     type: requestType,
     url: url,       
     dataType: dataType,
     data: dataParams,
 ...
```

Where dataParams is

```
 {"title":{},"iSBN":"111","partNumber":"3332","bookCategory":"1"}
```

title being undefined.