# TypeError: click called on object that does not implement interface HtmlElement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen the [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20482392/typeerror-click-called-on-an-object-that-does-not-implement-interface-htmlele) on this topics, but i can't spot the error in my code.

```
$('#submit_bulk').on('click',function(e){

    var action = $('select[name="bulk_action"]'),
    targets = $('table tr td:first-child :checkbox:checked');
    if(action=='invalid' || targets.length == 0){
        sk.alert('Nothing to do','warning');
        return false;
    }else{
        $(this).html('Working....');

        var fData = {
            action: action,
            mixtapes: '',
            singles: ''
        };

        $.each(targets,function(i,v){
            if($(this).data('type') == 'mixtape'){
                fData.mixtapes += $(this).data('id')+',';
            }else{
                fData.singles += $(this).data('id')+',';
            }
        });

        fData = $.param(fData); 

        console.log(fData); //i get no output here. is fData null?

        $.post(window.location.origin+'/adminAPI/bulk_action',fData,function(data){
            var data = JSON.parse(data);
            if(data.error==0){
                sk.alert('Your changes were saved','success');
                //update view here.
            }else{
                sk.alert(data.message,'error');
            }
        });
        $(this).html('go');
    }

});
```

Comment: could you reference a jsfiddle?

Comment: can you add debugger before $.each and after fdata lets see realtime changings of the var

Comment: I'm a damn idiot, that's what it was. it was the `action` variable. its value is a jQuery object, forgot to call `val()` on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Word to the wise. make sure you are not passing a `jQuery selector` as a value into your form data.

the offending line was:

`var action = $('select[name="bulk_action"]')`

should have been:

`var action = $('select[name="bulk_action"]').val()`

Comment: I was using `$.map()` to build an array of values. It was building a jquery object instead, which my ajax call didn't like. Thanks for posting this information or I never would have known.