# What is wrong with my `$.ajax()` call in the `data` part?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

As first what I want, is when I scroll to the bottom of the page there will load 5 new posts from the database.

I'm doing a `$.ajax()` call where I give;

- method: "POST"
- url: "gastenboek_load_posts.php"
- data: { 'rows': rows }

I did put an `alert()` on every single place to check where is goes wrong, and commented lines out of what I was thinking that was wrong.

And I came by the part of `data: { 'rows': rows }`

How can it be that this gives an error that says;

**`TypeError: 'click' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLElement.`
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js
`Line 4`**

This is the whole `jQuery` code;

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
    {
        var rows = $("#feedback_field").find(".gb_list_item");

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "gastenboek_load_posts.php",
            data: { 'rows': rows}
        }).done(function(data){
            $("#feedback_field").append(data);
        });
    }
});
```

Maybe the `PHP response` code for if you need it what I think is not important for this problem;

```
<?
include_once 'core/init.php';
?>
<div id="feedback_field">
<ul>
    <?
    $a = 10;

    if (load_next_5_gb_posts($a) == false)
    {
        echo 'Alle gegevens zijn geladen!';
    }
    else
    {
        $posts = load_next_5_gb_posts($a);

        foreach ($posts as $data)
        {
            $a++;
        }
        ?><input type="hidden" id="new_posts" value="<?=$a?>"><?

        foreach ($posts as $posts)
        {
            ?>
            <li class="gb_list_item">
                <div id="poster">
                    <p><?=$posts['naam']?></p>
                    <p><?=$posts['email']?></p>
                    <p>
                        <?
                        $datum = $posts['datum'];
                        $week_days_en = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday");
                        $week_days_nl = array("Maandag", "Dinsdag", "Woensdag", "Donderdag", "Vrijdag", "Zaterdag", "Zondag");
                        $months_en = array("January", "February", "Mart", "April", "May", "June", "July", "Augustus", "September", "October", "November", "December");
                        $months_nl = array("Januari", "Februari", "Maart", "April", "Meiy", "Juni", "Juli", "Augustus", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December");
                        $date = date_create($datum);
                        echo str_replace($week_days_en, $week_days_nl, str_replace($months_en, $months_nl, date_format($date,"l d F Y")));
                        ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div id="msg">
                    <?=nl2br($posts['msg'])?>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?
        }
    }
    ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You are trying to pass an DOM Object with this `var rows = $("#feedback_field").find(".gb_list_item");`

Comment: What is the error you are getting at console log  ?

Comment: You may actualy need `var rows = $("#feedback_field").find(".gb_list_item").val()`?

Comment: `$("#feedback_field").find(".gb_list_item");` is not right. It should be value of something not the dom object.

Comment: @SandeepNayak No! that is jQuery object.

Comment: remove the " from the name of the properties. (in 'rows': rows)

Comment: @PHPWeblineindia That is no solution at first I did it without! ;)

Comment: @PHPWeblineindia: Was it inferred from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20482392/typeerror-click-called-on-an-object-that-does-not-implement-interface-htmlele

Comment: @SandeepNayak : yes. there are many similar possibilities for this issue. So this was the matching case

Comment: @Lenap would you clearly mention what do you want to post through ajax.

Comment: @Lenap : you can simply post the variable (page number value) in post and from php do the required records fetching stuff and return. this may help you.. http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/auto-load-records-on-page-scroll

Comment: @SandeepNayak No I need the amout of the `li's` that there are in the `ul`

Comment: Its rare to see code quite this bad! You do almost everything at least twice, including 2 database accesses to do exactly the same thing and loading reference arrays each time round a loop. Maybe if you started by refactoring this code completely you could see what is wrong. Soon you will need 2 servers to cope with the load of running one little application

Comment: I might also suggest that the __error you mention__ is not in any of the code you show. The error is related to a __click__ handler and you have not shown us that. **Use the browsers javascript debugger** to see the line **in your code** that actually generates this error

Comment: @RiggsFolly But how can it be when I remove the `data: { rows: rows }` part the error isn't there anymore? :s

Comment: Doing that will probably generate a javascript error and therefore NONE of the javascript will compile and therefore it wont actually run anything at all

Comment: @RiggsFolly This is so confusing me sorry, I'l just do it over :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution!!!

In the `jQuery` code this line needs the `.length` function;

**From**

```
var rows = $("#feedback_field").find(".gb_list_item");
```

**To**

```
var rows = $("#feedback_field").find(".gb_list_item").length;
```

What is ectually very logical, cuz without that function I dont get the amount of the `li's` ;)

Thx for you help guys!

Answer (score -1):

you forget .length in jquery.
try this:
 `var rows = $("#feedback_field").find(".gb_list_item").length;`